# How to send messages to iot edge hub using REST?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm using iot edge modules. I need to send messages to the hub from the edge module.
Per my understanding, I need to send it first to the iot edge hub, the edge hub will take care of transferring it to the cloud iot hub. I can consume it from there.

If that's supported, I'm looking for a REST sample on how to do that (or just REST documentation)

Answer (score 0):

To send data to the IoT Edge hub, a module calls the SendEventAsync method.

```
ModuleClient client = new ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(transportSettings); 
await client.OpenAsync(); 
await client.SendEventAsync(“output1”, message);
```

Checkout the below link for moduleclient class methods and properties.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.moduleclient?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: thanks. I'm actually looking for REST APIs. I don't use C#

Comment: @GeorgeMoussa Can you please share which language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to use the ModuleClient SDK if you want to sent messages through IoT Edge to the cloud. The alternative would be to use IoT Edge in a transparent gateway mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-connect-downstream-device

In this way your (virtual) device could connect to the Edge Hub just as it would connect directly to the IoT Hub - using AMQP, MQTT or - as you want to - HTTP.